# Get XPath of element where caret is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the xpath or element reference of the element where caret(text editing blinking cursor) is present, caret can be positioned either by mouse click or by using keyboard actions.

```
<div class="PPTOutlineViewContent" contentEditable="true" draggable="false">
<div class="PPTOutlineSlide_1 Slide">
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideNumber" contentEditable="false">1</div>
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleSpan line1">Seattle</div>
    <div class="PPTOutLineSubtitle line2">With Kodiak West Travel</div>

</div>

<div class="PPTOutlineSlide_2 Slide">
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideNumber" contentEditable="false">2</div>
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleSpan line1">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

<div class="PPTOutlineSlide_3 Slide">
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideNumber" contentEditable="false">3</div>
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleSpan line1">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

    <div class="PPTOutlineSlide_4 Slide">
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideNumber" contentEditable="false">4</div>
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleSpan line1">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="PPTOutlineSlide_5 Slide">
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideNumber" contentEditable="false">5</div>
```

suppose caret is present on this line

```
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleSpan line1">Visit Seattle</div> 

    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleDiv line2">Before or After</div>
    <div class="PPTOutlineSlideTitleDiv line3">Your Cruise to Alaska!</div>
    <div class="PPTOutLineSubtitle line4">Kodiak West Travel Can Help </div>
    <div class="PPTOutLineSubtitle line5">You Develop Your Itinerary</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

For Example: if caret is present before "Visit Seattle" on slide 5 line 2, I should get the xpath or element reference of that div element.

Comment: how does caret differ from other elements.

Answer (score 0):

A document can have one [`activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) at the time. If there's a blinking caret on a page, `activeElement` refers to that particular element. A jQuery object can be retrieved like so: `$(document.activeElement)`, or [`$( ":focus" )`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/).